# Rototiller needed for fresh fill?

Tags: soil, planting

I have a 200 sq. ft. area that has just been filled with dirt. I'm planning to add 2" of topsoil and then plant pachysandra. Since the dirt underneath has not been compacted, to I really need a rototiller to mix the soil or can I just do it with a rake?

Answer (score 3):

If the soil is not compacted, I would not attempt to disturb the soil. Doing so will expose weed seeds and disrupt the natural structure of the soil. Oddly, enough you run the risk of compacting the soil. There are two ways this could happen: the natural structure of the soil is stable, by rotavating it you make it unstable and it will soon collapse back down but without the tunnels of worms and so on it will collapse further than before. The other way, is that rotavators have a tendency to create hardpans at the bottom of where they are tilling.